# Flutter Where should I put boolean in Modal Bottom Sheet?

Tags: flutter

I wanted to change text 'tap' and 'tapped' with tap like this code below, but it doesn't change the text.
I can see`print(isTapped)`works, but why the text doesn't change?
Did I put `bool isTapped = false;` wrong place? or Am I totally misunderstanding?
I just want change the text 'tap' and 'tapped'.

I'm new to flutter and programming.

````
class TestBool extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestBool({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestBoolState createState() => _TestBoolState();
}

class _TestBoolState extends State<TestBool> {

  bool isTapped = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.red,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              isScrollControlled: true,
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => DraggableScrollableSheet(
                  initialChildSize: 0.5,
                  builder: (_, controller) => Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isTapped = !isTapped;
                        });
                        print(isTapped);
                      },
                      child: Center(child: Text(isTapped ? 'tap' : 'tapped')),
                    ),
                  )
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Image.asset('images/commenticon.png'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
} ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you are using a stateless ModalBottomSheet, so it doesn't have a state to update. The solution for this is to use `StatefulBuilder`, example:

```
Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.red,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              isScrollControlled: true,
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => 
               StatefulBuilder(
                builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter stateSetter  {return 
                    DraggableScrollableSheet(
                        initialChildSize: 0.5,
                        builder: (_, controller) => Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                isTapped = !isTapped;
                              });
                              print(isTapped);
                            },
                            child: Center(child: Text(isTapped ? 'tap' : 'tapped')),
                          ),
                        )
                );
          }));
          },
          child: Image.asset('images/commenticon.png'),
        ),
      ),
    );
```